# Definición de modelo Djando - 1 o 2 modelos

Tags: django

Cuando un usuario se registro, la información de importancia principal es el usuario, su contraseña y su email. Si, no existe el usuario y valida el email, entonces debe completar el resto de la información personal.

He aquí que al momento de definir los modelos decidí separarlos como se muestra a continuación.

```
class client(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField() 
       
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

class clientData(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(client, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    picture=models.ImageField() 
    qualification=models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return selft.user.user
```

Pero luego me surgió la duda. ¿No es más optimizado que todo esté en un mismo modelo? Yo lo había pensado y lo separé pensando que como el proceso de registro consta de 2 pasos, uno en que se ingresa el nuevo usuario con su contraseña y un email, el cual debe validarse para luego completar la información personal. Por lo que en la primera etapa, cuando crea su usuario, contraseña y agrega el email, la demás parte de la información estará incompleta.

¿Qué es más optimo? ¿Un solo modelo con valores default=None?

```
class client(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField() 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None)
    picture=models.ImageField(default=None) 
    qualification=models.IntegerField(default=0)
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

Comment: Si en muchos casos los campos van a estar vacíos, lo más correcto es tener un segundo modelo que directamente no tenga los campos que van a estar vacíos, pues a la hora de hacer envíos se usa menos ancho de banda. En este caso, lo vas a enviar solo una vez y apenas si hay un par de campos, que tampoco van a ser muy pesados de enviar, así que no creo que exista mucha diferencia entre una opción u otra. La otra opción sería tener un único modelo y que dentro lleve un objeto `data` que contenga la información que normalmente va en `None`, así solo tienes que enviar un único `None` cuando no está.

Comment: Y eso ¿no implicaría más procesamiento por parte del servidor si, por ejemplo quisiera buscar el nombre de un usuario? Porque debería realizar una búsqueda del usuario en la tabla de clientData y de allí el nombre.

Comment: Depende de cómo esté estructurada la base de datos. Depende incluso de qué tipo de base de datos uses... No has dado mucha información, es difícil responderte. En una DB noSql es exactamente lo mismo, simplemente el campo estará ahí o no. Por otro lado en una DB relacional tendrás que usar un *join*. La implementación variará, si. Pero no es *tan costoso* buscar en las dos tablas unidas, las bases de datos relacionales son capaces de gestionar tablas con millones y millones de filas, no te preocupes por eso. Si lo diseñas bien, puedes sacar el objeto entero con una sola query, tenga datos o no

Comment: Ambas maneras son validas, y puedes usar la manera que mas te guste. Yo prefiero tener los modelos separados, me gusta mas tener el codigo simple y facil de ordenar. Es importante señalar que en el primer enfoque se hacen 2 consultas a la bace de datos y en el segundo enfoque se hace solo una consulta